# Android studio error on updating to 3.1

Tags: 16.04, android, android-studio, android-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade Android studio to v3.1 but at the end this error is showing.

[Error gettng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOWvb.png)

This access denied error is showing.